# Accessing C# code hosted on US server from Local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have recently created a website in asp.net with c# and hosted it on US server,
Now my problem is I want to access its code from local machine,
Is it possible to access the code of US server from my local machine? 
because when any changes suggested by my boss each I want to access that server and do the changes which is tedious task to do,

What I did for same:-

1. I selected the open website in visual studio 2005 and select Remote Site option 
   It ask me for Enter URL of website configured with the FrontPage Server Extensions
   Under which a textbox appear saying Https://
2. Then I went to US server and install the FrontPage server Extension as told in the web site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298158

What do I enter in the text box of Visual Studio 2005 asking me for Website Location to access my code on US server from my local machine

Answer (score 3):

You will supply the URL to the site, or FTP credentials to access the files.

However, I am going to recommend against this approach, as developing directly against a production server is NEVER a good idea.  A local copy that you then publish off to the server is a more appropriate solution, and in the end will most likely save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* access the remote site to make changes directly.  You should have a server on site that you use for development and testing, and have the code for the site under source control.  Then, when you want to make changes you get the project from source control, make the changes there so that they can be tracked, and use the local server to test anything.

Only then do you need to worry about changing anything on the remote server.  Normally the way you need to do this is that your service provider for the server will only give you ftp access.  So you publish from visual studio to your local file system and ftp those files up to the remote server.

Comment: I dont get how to get the project from Source control 
please be more specific,

I did all the things that has been told by 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298158 site
I have the server on the site which i use for development and testing where Visual Studio 2005 ,IIS, as well as Dotnet Framework 3.5 is installed i have all the credentials to access the server. 

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav Deshpande

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to build ASP.NET web applications.

What you *should* do is use source control and keep all of your code there. I prefer Subversion. Then you can deploy your compiled binaries to the server of your choice using the [Publish command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx).

Comment: Please be more specific, sense i am a beginner in asp.net with c#
and please tell me what am i asking is possible?

in visual studio 2005 asking me for Website Location to access my code from Remote site 

if it is possible to access the code of Remote site from Visual studio 2005
what URL i type there is my question?

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav Deshpande